# SQL - Delete row based on number of rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers

How would I go about deleting a row from the table 'subjects' that has a primary id 'subject_id' based on the number of rows in another table named 'replies' that uses a 'subject_id' column as a reference.

Example in pseudo code: 
If ('subject' has less than 1 reply){
delete 'subject'}

I don't know much about SQL triggers so I have no clue if I would be able to incorporate this directly in the database or if I'd have to write some PHP code to handle this...

Comment: There are several answers below, and not one interaction from you in two days - you should review the answers, and upvote/accept those you find helpful. This allows us to know you found a working solution, and be able to offer further assistance if something's not working to your satisfaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete any subjects that have had no replies, this query should do the trick:

```
DELETE s.* FROM subjects AS s
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT r.subject_id
    FROM replies AS r
    WHERE r.subject_id = s.subject_id
    );
```

**Demo:** [DB Fiddle Example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x6zi5nyjAVV8SGVdrJKbXp/0)

Comment: Wow thanks! You just opened my eyes to triggers, it was really simple to add in phpMyAdmin. I think this is the next thing I'll focus on learning!

Answer (score 1):

One of the MySQL gurus will need to weigh in on whether or not you can do this directly, but in PHP you could...

```
$query = "SELECT subject_id FROM subjects WHERE subject='test'";
$return = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
$id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return);

$query = "SELECT reply_id FROM replies WHERE subject_id='".$id[0]."'";
$return = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($return) < 1){
    $query = "DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id='1'";
    $return = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
}
```

This example assumes the "subject" is unique.  In other words, SELECTing WHERE subject='test' will only ever return one subject_id.  If you were doing this as a periodic cleaning, you would grab all the subject_id values (no WHERE clause) and loop through them to remove them if no replies.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in one query by selecting all (unique) subject-ids from the `replies` table, and delete all subjects that *doesn't* have a reply in there. Using `SELECT DISTINCT`, you don't get the IDs more than once (if a subject has more than one reply), so you don't get unnecessary data.

```
DELETE FROM subjects 
WHERE subject_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT subject_id FROM replies)
```

Any subject that doesn't have a reply should be deleted!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to delete all subjects with no replies:

```
DELETE FROM subjects WHERE subject_id NOT IN 
(SELECT subject_id FROM replies);
```

I think this is what you want...